# How to split "-2-2" to -2,2 ? (I want to split this string only by middle '-' in Java)

Tags: java, split

How should I write in spilit method ?

```
     String str = "-2-8";
     String[] array =   str.split("?");
```

Comment: What about `-2-8-6`?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array=str.substring(1).split("-");
array[0]=str.charAt(0).toString()+array[0];
```

Split the substring from index 1 by **-**. Then again add the leading **-** to the front of the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex you can do it for any number, instead only 0-9.

```
String text = "-2-8";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(\\-\\d+)");

Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
while (m.find())
   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
```

A good regex tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm